# Why is VSCode debugger not finding Node process to attach to?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm testing out the VS Code node debugger, but I'm not able to find any node processes when trying to attach to a running process.

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

the contents of my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./bin/www"
  }
```

After I start up the process using 'npm start', I press 'start debug' and the list of node processes is:

- 1 sssd_pam
- 1 sssd_nss
- 1 sssd_be

Looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wBEp.png) and none of these are the server I just launched.
This list persists even after I take down the node server.

Why am I not able to see any of my running node processes in the VSCode process attach?

P.s. I'm closely following [this](https://youtu.be/2oFKNL7vYV8) tutorial on debugging Node.js with VS Code.

Comment: Please, post the scripts in your `package.json` file so we can help. Maybe there's a problem with the NPM Start script.

Comment: Edited the post to include that.

Comment: After adding  --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 to the npm script, it is now working. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running the NodeJS in debug mode inside `npm start`? You need to use the `--inspect` flag. Without this flag, the NodeJS interpreter won't open the debug port to the VSCode to attach to.

Refer to: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Another option is to attach using a port definition. I usually do something like this in the launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229,
  "restart": true,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Then I start the NodeJS process as: `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 start.js`